# Error : Metadata contains reference that cannot be resolved: Dynamics 365 online

Tags: web-services, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

I'm trying to create web service (ASMX) to connect with the D365.
But when I'm trying to connect to the D365, I got this error message :-

[image]

I tried to change the DLL to the latest version but still gave me same error. For more details about my code :-

```
public class CRMConnection
{
    public OrganizationServiceProxy service;
    private ClientCredentials credentials;
    private String UserName = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CRM_Username"];
    private String Password = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CRM_Password"];

    public CRMConnection()
    {
        Uri OrganizationUri = new Uri(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CRM_URL"]);

        credentials = new ClientCredentials();
        credentials.UserName.UserName = UserName;
        credentials.UserName.Password = Password;

        service = new OrganizationServiceProxy(OrganizationUri, null, credentials, null);
    }
}
```

Error comes in this line :

```
service = new OrganizationServiceProxy(OrganizationUri, null, credentials, null);
```

My project Target Framework is 4.5.2

Note : I used same code with other project (Windows Application) and it's working fine.

Your help in this regard will be highly appreciated!

Thanks ..

Comment: I tried many versions of DLL , and I changed my project target Framework to 4.6.1.
still getting same error :( .

Comment: Could you try using the constructor (IServiceConfiguration<IOrganizationService>, ClientCredentials)? You can use the ServiceConfigurationFactory to create it from your url to the organization service in D365. Also use the latest version of the Xrm SDK.

Answer (score -1):

This case has been resolved. The issue was because of the proxy settings .

Comment: @ Majed Al-Omair Could you please Share here what you mean by proxy settings changes